# Object references in HashMap

Tags: java, collections

How do the below code provides value of the Employee  object e2 as employee even I didn't add e2 to the HashMap. I would like to know how e2 is referred here.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Employee {
    int phno;
    String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Employee e1=new Employee();
   e1.name="niks";
   e1.phno=9032944566;
   HashMap<Employee,String> m=new HashMap();
   m.put(e1, "employee1");
   Employee e2=new Employee();
   e2.name="niks";
   e2.phno=9032944566;
   System.out.println("value of e2:"+m.get(e2));
    }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + phno;
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (phno != other.phno)
        return false;
    return true;
}
 }
```

**Output**
  value of e2: employee1

Comment: You looked up an equal key to the one you put in there. Why would you expect not to get the associated value?

Comment: `HashMap` uses object equaltity check to find keys in the map. Your equality function of `Employee` (`equals`) overriden and returns `true` if both `name` and `phno` fields of employee are equals. So if you run `e1.equals(e2)` it return `true`. `HashMap` uses this method to find a key.

Answer (score 2):

They have distinct references, but their values are equals since you override the equals method.

What the method get() gonna do is to call your **haschode** and  **equals** method.
If the hashCode of two Objects in a Map returns the same number, then equals will be called to determine if they're equal...

```
Employee newReference = new Employee();
Employee newReference2 = new Employee();
newReference.name="MyName";
newReference2.name="MyName";

map.put(newReference);
map.get(newReference2); //key.equals(key2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to be noted here:

1) The two instances of the Employee object - e1 & e2 are *equal* -- because they meet the criteria defined in the *equals()* and *hashcode()* methods of the Employee class.

2) A hashmap cannot have duplicate keys. So, as soon as *put()* is called with the same key (e2, which is same object as e1) it gets replaced within the map.

Comment: I have not used put for e2 though.

Comment: you did call put() for e1. And as far as the jvm is concerned; e1 is same as e2.

Answer (score 0):

its because their phno number and name are same and they create same hashcode

test this code to see what i mean

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    System.out.println("res : "+result);
    result = prime * result + phno;
    System.out.println("res : "+result);
    return result;
}
```

output :

```
res : 3381378
res : 104823717
res : 3381378
res : 104823717
value of e2:employee1
```